# Files in Python 3.6.1 : save and restore

Tags: python-3.x, file, pickle

I have a problem with a function that I wrote to save and restore scores from a file using Python. I've wrote the function many times using different ideas but I still didn't get to the right way to make it work and I don't even understand what is the problem, each time it shows a different error.

def save_score(p_Name):

```
os.chdir("D:\Mine!\Python_projects\Jeu_Pendu")
print(scores)
if p_Name in scores.keys():

    with open('scores.txt','ab') as mes_scores:
        my_pickler=pickle.Pickler(mes_scores)
        my_pickler.dump(scores)

else:

    score = 0
    scores[p_Name] = score        #scores is a dict()
    with open('scores.txt', 'rb') as mes_scores:
        mon_depickler=pickle.Unpickler(mes_scores)
        score_restore=mon_depickler.load()
```

Comment: Use *raw strings* for file names.

Comment: Can you show some examples of the error messages you get? Full tracebacks would be ideal.